# how to integrate twitter login to my website using script

Tags: javascript, twitter

How to implement twitter login to my website.I created consumer key and secrect key.I dont know how to trigger twitter sign button to my page and retrive user data.

**1.**
logIn is not defined[Uncaught ReferenceError: logIn is not defined].

**2.**
how can i retrive user login details.

Anyone can help me.

```
    <a  onclick="logIn()" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <img src="<?php echo url(); ?>/images/sign-in-with-twitter-gray.png" title="twitter"></a>

   <script type="text/javascript">  
   var digitsKey = 'Rvs7W4lsOiIJkZyYrMYVkLMEs';

  Digits.init({ consumerKey: digitsKey })
  .done(function() {
    console.log('Digits initialized.');
   })
   .fail(function(error) {
    console.log('Digits failed to initialize: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
   });
   Digits.logIn()
    .done(function(loginResponse) {

      var params = {
        provider: 'twitter_digits',
        twitter_digits: loginResponse.oauth_echo_headers
      };

      // login with twitter_digits params
      QB.login(params, function(err, user){
        if (user) {

        }else{

        }
      });

    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      console.log('Digits failed to login: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: how can i use javascript.

Comment: any demo/source using javascripot

Comment: Have you gone through **[this](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing)** Document  yet ?

Comment: how to generate digitsKey in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the twitter's api documentation, you can see how to do the login.

I think your question is how insert a plugin to login similar than facebook but I think they don't did any library.

- When the user clicks the loggin button you must send a post request to twitter to get the oauth_token:

Example: POST request to "api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

and then, twitter provides you the oauth_token and the oauth_token_secret (private).

- Once you did this step you must to redirect the user to twitter.

Example: GET request to "api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_GIVEN_IN_STEP_1"

If everything has gone well twitter response you with the oauth_token and a verifier oauth token.

Let's set up the last step!

- Send a post request to twitter api endpoint with the verifier oauth token provided in the response of step 2.

Example: POST request to "api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token" sending the verifier oauth token as post parameter.

And then twitter response with a secret token and the user token, you can save it and feel free to use it in any twitter endpoint.

**Login documentation:** https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing
**Browser auth flow:** https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/desktop-browser

Regards!

Comment: Asking full sample code is being little bit lazy. He already gave you more than enough information to research.

Comment: can i do like facebook its possible